# Mockito - Verfication of another object's method call inside target class method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing a unit test for a method that involves cookies. Here is the method.

```
public Boolean addPropertyToUserWishlist(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, String propId) throws IOException {
    String message = "";
    try {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (checkCookieValueExists(cookies, propId)) {
            message = "Already added to favourites!";
        } else {
            if (checkCookieExists(cookies)) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    if ("favourites".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                        cookie.setValue(cookie.getValue() + "_" + propId);
                        cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5);
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                        message = "Added to Favourites!";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Cookie c = new Cookie("favourites", propId);
                c.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5);
                response.addCookie(c);
                message = "Added to Favourites!";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is the unit test for the method.

```
@Test
public void testAddPropertyToUserWishlist() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("addPropertyToUserWishlist");

    //decleration
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    Cookie c = mock(Cookie.class);
    Cookie[] cookies = new Cookie[2];
    String propId = "5"; //testing the for property with id 5
    WishlistController instance = Mockito.spy(new WishlistController());

    // training
    Mockito.doReturn(false).when(instance).checkCookieExists(cookies);
    Mockito.doReturn(false).when(instance).checkCookieValueExists(cookies, propId);
    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(cookies);

    // testing
    Boolean result = instance.addPropertyToUserWishlist(request, response, propId);
    //verify(response, times(1)).addCookie(c);
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

I wanted to test if the cookie was created. Since I am not executing this code in the browser. So How can I verify if the constructor for creating new cookie was called and the methods `setMaxAge` was called once?

Comment: verify if `response.addCookie` was called and captured the cookie that was passed in the argument. assert it's values if known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Cookie` is being created within the method under test there is not really any way for you to control its behavior, so there is no reason to mock it either.

Instead `verify` if `response.addCookie` was called and captured the cookie that was passed in as the argument.

From there, assert its values if known.

```
//Arrange
//...code removed for brevity

// Act
Boolean result = instance.addPropertyToUserWishlist(request, response, propId);

//Assert
ArgumentCaptor<Cookie> cookieCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Cookie.class);

//Same as verify(response, times(1)) and captures the passed argument
verify(response).addCookie(cookieCaptor.capture());

Cookie cookie = cookieCaptor.getValue();

int expectedAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5;
String expectedName = "favourites";

assertEquals(expectedAge, cookie.getMaxAge());
assertEquals(expectedName, cookie.getName());
assertEquals(propId, cookie.getValue());
```

Reference [Class `ArgumentCaptor<T>`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Comment: Thankyou so much, Thank you for your time. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Move cookie creation to a new method:

```
     } else {
            Cookie c = createNewCookie("favourites", propId);
            c.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5);
...
...
...

protected Cookie createNewCookie(String name, String id){
    return new Cookie(name, id);
}
```

and then in the unit test verify if this method was called:

```
@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;

@Mock
HttpServletResponse response;

@BeforeTest
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testAddPropertyToUserWishlist() throws IOException {

    WishlistController testedObject = Mockito.spy(new WishlistController());

    Boolean outcome = testedObject.addPropertyToUserWishlist(request, response, "propid");

    Mockito.verify(testedObject).createNewCookie("favourites","propid");
}
```

---

If you want to test operations done on the new cookie, you can override this method and inject your own instance of cookie into the test class in this way:

```
@Mock
Cookie myNewCookie;

@Test
public void testAddPropertyToUserWishlist() throws IOException {

    WishlistController testedObject = Mockito.spy(new WishlistController(){
        @Override
        protected Cookie createNewCookie(String id, String name){
            return myNewCookie;
        }
    });

    Boolean outcone = testedObject.addPropertyToUserWishlist(request, response, "propid");

    Mockito.verify(testedObject).createNewCookie("favourites","propid");
    Mockito.verify(myNewCookie, Mockito.times(1)).setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5);
}
```